# Intercept Apache communication

Tags: apache-2.2

I am looking to develop a solution that eliminates potential spammers. The way this system will work is that it will watch connections and requests. Going into the specifics is more for stackoverflow, But, what I am interested in is if it is possible to tell Apache to pass the request over to my application first and give it the ability to accept/deny the request. Sure, it will make requests slower, but I think that is a trade off I am willing to take. I still want, however, Apache to run the request through any interpreters (such as PHP).

The idea is that one wouldn't have to implement anti-spam measures on a per app basis but have an "umbrella" of spam protection.

Answer (score 1):

This already exists. Look into `mod_security` for something with some form behind it or alternatively `mod_perl` if you want to homebrew the whole thing - `mod_perl` has access/visibility into nearly the entire apache request/response process.